# Find if a class is already loaded in python?

Tags: python

How can we find out that a class is already loaded or not. I am performing dynamic loading of class using the following code :

```
module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
class_ref = getattr(module, class_name)
```

I am not sure if this method reloads the class if it is already present. I want the class to be loaded only once and have all the references point to the same class.

Comment: `import` machinery is `idempotent`

Comment: Put a `print` call in the module being loaded and see if it's being loaded twice.

Comment: What would you do with this information if it was available? You still need to get a reference to the class when you need it, so what would you do differently either way?

Comment: @hansolo so every reference will point to the same loaded class then right ?

Comment: @deceze if the two references point to two different loaded classes then they cannot be used interchangeably when class variables are involved

Comment: `isinstance(A, type)` is true only if class A is defined in your scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use a try-except:

```
try:
    dummy_variable = YourClass()
except NameError:
    # "YourClass" is not defined yet
    # Act accordingly (set a flag for example, to use later on in your code)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work if the `NameError` is raised within `YourClass` for example if you dont' pass the right parameters.